# Extract line of text from div using jSoup selector

Tags: jsoup

This is html code:

```
 <div class="comment">

        <a name="comment2609098"></a>
        <div class="mediadbgalleryfloat" style="margin: 0 14px 0 0;">
<div style="width: 75px; height: 75px;" class="mediadbgallery relative">
    <span class="edge"></span>
    <div class="container">
        <div style="overflow: hidden; width: 75px; height: 75px; position: relative;"><a href="https://www.meinbezirk.at/kitzbuehel/profile/hel-mut-130701.html" class="pointer">           <img src="https://media05.regionaut.meinbezirk.at/2017/11/07/13630293_thumb.jpg?1510079257" class="noborder" style="position: absolute; top: -5px; right: 0px; width: 75px; height: 84px; border: 0;" alt="Hel Mut" title="Hel Mut"></a></div></div>

    <span class="floatingUserPointsLow">157</span>                      

        </div>
</div>

                        <a href="https://www.meinbezirk.at/kitzbuehel/profile/hel-mut-130701.html">Hel Mut</a>
            aus <a href="https://www.meinbezirk.at/tirol/kitzbuehel/">Kitzbühel</a>
            | 22.01.2018 | 05:13                        &nbsp;                  <a class="metaReport right" title="Kommentar melden" href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="AJAX.overlay.showOverlay('reportContent', {type: 'comment', permalink: 'https://www.meinbezirk.at/kitzbuehel/politik/querulanten-braucht-man-nicht-d2381342.html#comment2609098'}); AJAX.overlay.lockOverlay(true, 'Wird geladen...');">Melden</a>
                            <div class="clearright"></div>

        <div class="spacerM"></div>
        <p class="hidden">
            Ein sehr interessantes Thema! Ich beobachte das auch schon seit längerem!           </p>
        <div class="clearboth"></div>
    </div>
```

I need to extract date, in this case it is 22.01.2018. I need to do this using only jSoup Selector.

I tried

```
 div.comment div.container :eq(n)
```

n - various numbers

```
 div.comment a:eq(3)
```

I really don't know how to get given text :(

I appreciate any help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to get close to the required string:

1. use `doc.select("div.comment").first().ownText();` as already mentioned by @Keizo, which will return `aus | 22.01.2018 | 05:13`   or
2. use `doc.select("div.comment").first().select("a").last().previousSibling();` if your html has always the same structure and the text you need is always between the last and secondlast link (a-tag), which will return `| 22.01.2018 | 05:13 &nbsp;`

I do not see other selectors or selector commbinations which could give you only  `22.01.2018`

Answer (score 0):

22.01.2018 is text of div class="comment" and you can retrieve the date with regex like as below.

```
    public void test() {
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(your url).get();

        // get <div class="comment">
        Element comment = doc.select("div.comment").first();

        // retrieve the date inside "|" 
        String regex = "\\|(.*?)\\|";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(comment.text());

        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));  // 22.01.2018
        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I need jsoup selector, if I could do this in Java, it would already be done

Comment: I think you can't  do that with only selector.

Comment: There has to be a way :(